# Como impedir exclusão de um trecho html?

Tags: jquery

Bom Dia Gente,
Tenho o código

```
<Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO> 

VÁRIOS CODIGOS HTML AQUI DENTRO.

</Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO>
```

O que eu quero fazeR?
Quero saber se é possível eu impossibilitar que o que tiver com a tag  `<Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO> e fechando  </Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO>` quero impossibilitar o usúario dele apagar esse trecho com essas tags, ou seja ele vai dar um backspace e o texto vai voltar.
Ou o backspace ficar inativo nestes trechos é possível?

Comment: Se for possível, por favor  o código? tentei e nada consegui , obrigada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar esse código em um elemento oculto, e depois ir verificando, a cada modificação, se ele está no textarea.

```js
/* Captura o valor dos dados que NÃO podem ser apagados */
var elementoOculto = document.querySelector("#elemento-oculto");

/* Captura o valor da caixa de edição */
var elementoNormal = document.querySelector("#elemento-normal");

/* Adiciona evento para detectar a tecla pressionada antes da ação dela. */
elementoNormal.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
  
    /* Captura onde o cursor está localizado no textarea "normal" */
    let selectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    let selectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
    
    /**
     * Subtrai a posição de início para n-1, dessa forma será
     * possível capturar a letra anterior a posição do cursor
     */
    if (selectionStart === selectionEnd) {
      selectionStart--;
    }
    
    /* Caso o usuário aperte a tecla Delete, captura a letra seguinte. */
    if (e.keyCode === 46 && (selectionEnd - selectionStart) === 1) {
      selectionStart++;
      selectionEnd++;
    }
    
    /* Captura a letra ou seleção de letras deletadas. */
    let newValue = this.value.slice(0, selectionStart) + this.value.slice(selectionEnd);
    
    /* Verifica se o novo valor possui o mesmo código da textarea elemento oculto */
    if ( newValue.indexOf(elementoOculto.value) === -1 ) {
    
      /* Caso não possua o mesmo valor, impede a ação do usuário. */
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#elemento-oculto {
  display: none;
  visibility: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Adicione no valor desse elemento, O CÓDIGO QUE NÃO PODERÁ SER DELETADO. -->
<textarea id="elemento-oculto"><Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO> 

VÁRIOS CODIGOS HTML AQUI DENTRO.

</Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO></textarea>




<!-- Esse outro elemento, é onde o usuário poderá deletar os dados. -->
<textarea id="elemento-normal" rows="10" cols="60">
Blá blá blá blá
<Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO> 

VÁRIOS CODIGOS HTML AQUI DENTRO.

</Sua IMAGEM ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APAGUE ESTE CODIGO>

Blá blá blá blá

</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Isso deve funcionar para você

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   var elid = $(document.activeElement).hasClass('textInput');
   if (e.keyCode === 8 && !elid) {
    return false;
   };
});
```

o e.keyCode é a identificação da tecla backspace do teclado. Precisa adaptar para o seu form